# How to set up a home network

Tags: 11.10, sharing

I have been using windows 7 on both my home pc and my laptop and have been using the Homegroup feature to share files between machines.

Could someone please tell me how to achieve this using ubuntu 11.10 in the easiest way possible?

Via a graphical interface would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You want to install Samba. By terminal or through Software center. You can then setup to view your Ubuntu files on a Windows computer. To do this you need to tell Samba what folders you want to share like Music or Pictures. Go to Samba and click the green add button. THat will let you add a folder to be shared.  However, I have not figured out how to view files from Windows computers on Ubuntu yet...

Comment: Ive tried samba and yes i can view my shared ubuntu folders from my windows machine no problem but not the other way around.I am kinda familiar sharing windows to windows so all right things are ticked in windows and sharing has never been a problem.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I do not know that. I am still learning myself.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a new resource in Samba and it will be shared.

Comment: I cant get samba to work the gui wont load